# How to extract PDF attachments from Outlook and save to Folder

Tags: vba, outlook

I need VBA code to use in Outlook to extract the PDF attachments from emails and save into a designated folder. The user will choose the emails.

I have the below code but need it amended.

```
Public Sub SaveAutoAttach(item As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim object_attachment As Outlook.Attachment

Dim saveFolder As String
' Folder location when I want to save my file
saveFolder = "D:\Data\Archive"

    For Each object_attachment In item.Attachments
' Criteria to save .doc files only
    If InStr(object_attachment.DisplayName, ".doc") Then

        object_attachment.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & object_attachment.DisplayName

    End If

    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: i think you need to change the `.doc` with `.pdf` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

As per your request, the following macro will save any PDF attachments from one or more user selected items.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SaveAttachmentsFromSelectedItemsPDF()

    Dim currentItem As Object
    Dim currentAttachment As Attachment
    Dim saveToFolder As String
    Dim savedFileCountPDF As Long

    saveToFolder = "c:\users\domenic\desktop" 'change the path accordingly

    savedFileCountPDF = 0
    For Each currentItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        For Each currentAttachment In currentItem.Attachments
            If UCase(Right(currentAttachment.DisplayName, 4)) = ".PDF" Then
                currentAttachment.SaveAsFile saveToFolder & "\" & _
                    Left(currentAttachment.DisplayName, Len(currentAttachment.DisplayName) - 4) & "_" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd_hh-mm-ss") & ".pdf"
                savedFileCountPDF = savedFileCountPDF + 1
            End If
        Next currentAttachment
    Next currentItem

    MsgBox "Number of PDF files saved: " & savedFileCountPDF, vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: There will be some PDFs that have the same generic name and would be good to be able to rename them as they are extracted.

Comment: I have edited the code so that a date and time stamp is added to the filename.  This will give each one a unique filename.